# How does the compiler not confuse local variable named size with function call size()?

Tags: c++, scope, local

While reading a C++ textbook, I came across this specific piece of code:

```
vector<double> homework;
typedef vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
vec_sz size = homework.size();
```

I wonder how isn't there any conflict during compilation since the local variable `size` and the function being called `size()` share the same name and (here expecting a correction if I am wrong) they are apparently in the same scope.
If they aren't in the same scope, then how does the compiler handle these two names in a single statement?

Thanks for your time in advance I hope my question makes sense!

Comment: Because `size` in `homework.size()` is a qualified name.

Comment: *"I hope my question makes sense!"* -- it makes sense, but here's one for you. How would you make sense of the expression `homework.size()` if `size` named the variable? (Context matters!)

Comment: when you do `class_name.class_member`, the compiler only looks for the name in `class_name`, thus no possible ambiguity,

Comment: If they were in the same scope you wouldn't need the `homework.` to access the `size` member.

Answer (score 2):

> how isn't there any conflict during compilation since the local variable size

Because `size` in `homework.size()` is a **qualified name**. While the name `size` without any qualification is an **unqualified name**. When you wrote `homework.size()` only the **class scope** corresponding to the class name `homework` is searched.  So there is no clash between the two names if you were to write:

```
//----vvvv-------------------->local variable named size
      size = homework.size();
//--------------------^^^^---->data member named size in class scope
```

Comment: there can be a clash between a qualified name and a unqualified name. The reason they dont clash is because the qualified name does not refer to the same as the unqualified name

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number For the expression `homework.size()` only the class scope corresponding to the class name `homework` is searched.  Can you give one example where there is a clash between a qualified name and a unqualified name? I think that the clash that you're talking about may happen when ADL is involved or maybe something else.

Comment: when there is a `foo` in global namespace then `foo` (unqualified) and `::foo` (qualified) may refer to the same `foo`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes as suspected.